# How to Know my scrollview is empty

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I want to know my scrollview does not have any content, then i want put if else condition.
like

```
 if (_scrollView == 0)
    {
      [self.addView setHidden:YES];
    }
```

Comment: you can check for Subview count. `NSArray *arrSubviews = [myScrollView subviews];`  If array count is 0 then scrollview has no content.

Comment: i used if ( arrSubviews.count == 0) but this not work. "if not get true"

Answer (score 1):

You can check **subview's count**. If count is greater than 0, then your scrollview has subview.

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

int currentCount = (int)scrollview.subviews.count;

NSLog(@"Current Count: %d", currentCount);
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lbl.text = @"Temp";
[scrollview addSubview:lbl];

currentCount = (int)scrollview.subviews.count;
NSLog(@"After Added Count: %d", currentCount);
```